# Make barplot with ggplot but doesnt show bars

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a data set like this

```
df1 
Ch   V
A    x1
B    x1
C    x2
D    x3
E    x2
..
```

I want to plot with a barplot the number of times V has been shown (on the y axis) while the values of V are shown on the x axis
I tried this

```
df2 <- table(df$V)
```

```
df2
V1    Freq
x1     3
x2     4
..
```

(numbers for Freq are random in this example)
and received a table to plot and my code for plotting using ggplot2 is

```
ggplot(df2, aes(x=V1, y=Freq)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

It doesn't show me the bars though they are simply not shown.
I made sure the values from df are both numerica.

What's the problem?
Thank you!

Comment: you wrote `x = Var1` but in `df2` it is `V1`. Have you try: `aes(x = V1 ...)` ?

Comment: yes @dc37 i tried it and it doesnt work

Comment: how about using `df1`: `ggplot(df1, aes(x=V)) + geom_bar(aes(y = ..count..))` or `ggplot(df1, aes(x=V)) + geom_bar(stat = "count")`

Comment: @Ben this also just shows an "empty" plot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@antonina - here is an example based on your post - can you reproduce this plot?

```
library(ggplot2)

df1 <- data.frame(
  Ch = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
  V = c("x1", "x1", "x2", "x3", "x2")
)

ggplot(df1, aes(x=V)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "count")
```

(or)

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x=V)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = ..count..))
```

[image: example ggplot]

**Edit**: Based on your comment, it might make sense to manipulate your data prior to plotting (e.g., using `aggregate` or `tidyverse` package). However, if you want to quickly plot counts for `x1`, `x2`, and `x3` in a single bar, as you requested, then subset your data and include a single string or number for x aesthetic, something like:

```
ggplot(df1[df1$V %in% c("x1", "x2", "x3"),], aes(x = "Single")) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "count")
```

Again, I'm a bit confused on what you are looking for. I hope that this is helpful.

Comment: i know this is the right answer but somehow my R doesn't work with it. Could it be that it doesnt show the bars because the x range is too large?

Comment: Did you try the code I provided exactly as shown? Was the result with axes and labels but no bars in the plot? Or is the entire plot empty/blank? What are you using for R (version? R Studio)? Have you had problems with anything like this before? Unfortunately this doesn't sound like a coding issue as much as something else. I wish I could be of more help here.

Comment: my xrange was to large and didn't show the plots anymore I think. Any way I can "sum" these? So for x1,x2,x3 one bar?

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the "x range" you mentioned. `V` seems to be a factor or character vector, not a continuous variable, unless I'm mistaken. What range are you referring to? Is this for another data set? As for taking the "sum" of the 3 bars, it might make more sense to manipulate the data before plotting the way you would like (such as `aggregate` or using `tidyverse`). However, I'll edit the answer to show a quick way to create a single bar plot of counts. Good luck!